# ListView item empty when use show layout bounds

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView show some information, the layout of item is the same. Using show       layout bounds tools, we can see like blow:
[image]

The above is the normal view layouts. But when I restart the app, I can see the below layouts bounds:
[image]

For item2, the view is normal if I don't open the "show layout bounds" tool. But I open it, the child view of item2 can't show the layout.

And item2 can not response to click event, item1 and item3 can.

What's the reason and how can I do to solve the problem.

Comment: can you share your code also?

Comment: find the reason. ListView getViewType do not override. all items is the same